# pdfmake - how to make very long image scroll down to second page?

Tags: jquery, html2canvas, pdfmake

I am using html2canvas to create dataURL of a html table.
This table is quite long. 
PDFmake take the image, scales it, and tries to make the image fit into a single page. That make the image very, very tiny. Even an ant can't read the contents of the image of the table.
I would like my image to scroll to as much pages as it would like to in the created pdf file.
Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I have edited this to represent what you want to do. Note you'll have to play around with the styles you want to get it looking how you want. Checkout the document I linked in the below comment.

JavaScript:

```
var yourPDF = {
    
    background: [
    {
       image: 'yourImage.jpg',
       width: x,
       height: y,
       margin: [a,b,c,d]
    }
   ],
    content: [
        {
            image: 'sampleImage.jpg',
            fit: [100, 100],
            pageBreak: 'after'
        },

        'I\'ll appear on page two with your image repeated',
    ],
    images: {
        building: 'your image location here'
    },
    
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I want I image to continue onto pages in the PDF file that is being created by PDFmake. Its a pdfmake question. But thank you for your answer. Appreciate it! :)

Comment: I just had a look at pdfmake's getting started document - [doc](http://pdfmake.org/index.html#/gettingstarted). They make mention of a background section. I have edited the above answer to what I think is what you're looking for.